# Java syntax (For) not included

Tags: java

```
for (int u: adjList.get(v))
{ 
    instructuion 
}
```

While processing an algorithm, I came across this Java syntax of the "For" loop that I can't figure out. I know that usually it is used like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < 6; i++) {
    instructuion 
}
```

What intrigues me here is the ":" in `int u: adjList.get(v)`. I know perfectly well that adjList is a list and u a variable of type integer.

I searched many sites, but none of them gave details on this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax "for-each loop" is used to iterate over a collection of items. In this example, the loop is saying: "for each item of type int in the list `adjList.get(v)`, execute the instruction". It is equivalent to writing a traditional for loop like the one you provided.

For example, the following code will print out the items in the list `adjList.get(v)`:

```
for (int u: adjList.get(v)) {
    System.out.println(u);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is called **for-each loop**. Let me give you an easy example
In the code below we mean that, for each number inside the numbers array.

```
int numbers[]={33,3,4,5}
// for each number inside the numbers array
for(int number : numbers){
   System.out.println(number);
}
```